# Creating a list or array from label text values in xamarin.Forms c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I've got a stack layout in Xamarin forms with a host of labels & images.

I need to iterate through the stack & where a label is found, move the text value of that label into an array or list. The labels come in sets of 3, but with a variable number of sets. Label 1 is always distance, Label 2 is duration and label 3 is instructions. So I'd like my list/array to have the structure below:

```
Entry|Distance|Duration|Instructions|

0----|181km---|28min---|Some text---|

1----|200km---|10min---|Some text---|
```

So every group of 3 labels needs to form one entry into a list as they are all associated. I've tried various methods, the closest I got is below (but not yet right as I'm getting an error on Case 1 & Case 2 where it says I'm using an unassigned variable. I think this is because it is only declared in Case 0). AM I close? Or is there a much more obvious way to get these values into the structure that I'm after?

Thanks in advance.

Created a class:

```
public class TripSteps
    {
        public int stage { get; set; }
        public string distance { get; set; }
        public string duration { get; set; }
        public string instructions { get; set; }
    }
```

& then added label text values to a list:

```
var x=0
var Step = 0  
List<TripSteps> Trip_Steps = new List<TripSteps>();
StackLayout route_stages_stack = (StackLayout)child;
var route_stages_children = route_stages_stack.Children;
foreach (var child2 in route_stages_children)
{
    if (child2.GetType() == typeof(Label))
    {
        Label new_text = (Label)child2;
        switch (x)
        {
            case 0: var step = new TripSteps(); step.stage = Step; step.distance = new_text.Text; x++; break;
            case 1: step.duration = new_text.Text; x++; break;
            case 2: step.instructions = new_text.Text; Trip_Steps.Add(step);  x = 0; Step++; break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a databound layout and databinding instead.  Parsing through a UI tree like this to extract data is generally not a great way to do things.  That said, try moving `var step = new TripSteps();` outside of the `switch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your variable is going out of scope after that first case exits: Try this:

```
var x=0
var Step = 0  
List<TripSteps> Trip_Steps = new List<TripSteps>();
StackLayout route_stages_stack = (StackLayout)child;
var route_stages_child

ren = route_stages_stack.Children;
var step = new TripSteps(); // Variable defined outside the loop and case statement now.
foreach (var child2 in route_stages_children)
{
    if (child2.GetType() == typeof(Label))
    {
        Label new_text = (Label)child2;
        switch (x)
        {
            case 0: step.stage = Step; step.distance = new_text.Text; x++; break;
            case 1: step.duration = new_text.Text; x++; break;
            case 2: step.instructions = new_text.Text; Trip_Steps.Add(step);  x = 0; Step++; step = new TripSteps();break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rapid reply - thank you! When I run that & then try                                 Trip_Steps.ForEach(Console.WriteLine); it writes only "Travel_Comp.TripSteps" to the console. How do I print out the list to check it's correct?

Comment: @stephen.webb You would writeout each property.  Your syntax is just writing out the class name, IE: the default of ToString() on the object.

Comment: Ah yes - of course. I also had to add in an if statement to re-initialise the step once it had looped over, otherwise it would create all records the same. Will update original question with solution - thanks for your help.

Comment: @stephen.webb FYI, if you look at the code at the end of Case 2:, it does reinit the step there.

Comment: Didn't scroll to the right - completely my mistake. Much neater solution too.